# Plotting error with matplotlib (no x-tick label)

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, plot

I'm trying to plot the following pandas dataframe (First column is the index):

```
          pressure mean  pressure std     Time
  Time                                          
00:00:00     618.663133      0.108484 00:00:00
01:00:00     618.281129      0.111788 01:00:00
02:00:00     617.975430      0.101657 02:00:00
03:00:00     617.766129      0.062712 03:00:00
04:00:00     617.807043      0.066030 04:00:00
05:00:00     617.976479      0.079755 05:00:00
06:00:00     618.276720      0.118224 06:00:00
.........
```

My goal is to plot Time (x axis) vs. pressure mean (y axis).
I want the x-axis to be with 2-hour ticks and H:M format.
I'm using the following code:

```
%matplotlib inline  

import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.dates as mdates
import datetime
from matplotlib.ticker import MultipleLocator, FormatStrFormatter



fig = plt.figure(figsize=(15,7))
ax = fig.add_subplot(1,1,1) # row-col-num
# --- line plot data on the Axes
ax.plot(df6['Time'], df6['pressure mean'], 'b-', linewidth=2,
label=r'Hawaii Pressure')
# -- Tick Label Size --
plt.rcParams['xtick.labelsize'] = 12 
plt.rcParams['ytick.labelsize'] = 16
# -- Tick Labels Format --
DaysFmt = mdates.DateFormatter('%H:%M')
minorLocator = MultipleLocator(5)
ax.xaxis.set_minor_locator(minorLocator)
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(DaysFmt)

# -- Axis Labels --
ax.set_ylabel(r'Pressure $[mb]$', fontsize=22)
ax.set_xlabel(r'Hour', fontsize=22)
# -- Tick Limits and Labels --
ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(mdates.HourLocator(interval=2))              

# -- Legend and Grid --
ax.legend(loc='best')
ax.grid(True)
# -- Title --
fig.suptitle('Stacked Hourly Pressure Averages (1 month)',fontsize=27)
fig.tight_layout(pad=5)
# -- Intervals --
fig.savefig('Hawaii Stacked Pressure October 2016.png', dpi=300)
```

But i'm getting a memory error, I know it's because of the following line:

```
ax.xaxis.set_minor_locator(minorLocator)
```

If I delete the line - i'm getting a plot without any x-axis tick labels !

Any suggestions?
Thanks !!

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution !

I just had to add conversion of the time string column to datetime:

```
df6['Time'] = pd.to_datetime(df6['Time'])
```

Yay!